# having trouble in displaying selected dates from calendar on dashboard in ionic 3 using angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

i use ionic calendar date picker to display calendar but getting problem to display date after selecting from calendar on dashboard. how to get this.

this is my code

.html file

```
  <ion-label>From Date</ion-label>
  <ionic-calendar-date-picker (onSelect)="dateSelected($event)" ></ionic-calendar-date-picker>  

<ion-label>To Date</ion-label>
<ionic-calendar-date-picker  (onSelect)="dateSelected($event)" ></ionic-calendar-date-picker>
```

.ts file

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

  @IonicPage()

  @Component({

  selector: 'page-view',

  templateUrl: 'view.html',

  })

  export class ViewPage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
  console.log('ionViewDidLoad ViewPage');

  }

  dateSelected($event)

  {
  console.log($event);

  }

}
```

Comment: Did you try in function dateSelected(event){console.log(event.target.value)};

Comment: yes i tried, showing error

Comment: Giving error since inside dataSelected(you put $event not event) so replace it with event.

Comment: still getting same error.when i click on date in calendar then giving error

Comment: What is the error given?

Comment: cannot read property 'value' of undefined.

Comment: Ok console.log the event and see the attributes it have, it may be target.value or target .nativeElement.value or .nativeElement.value, and if it didn't work simply declare calenderDate:any; in ts file .and in the html bind the calender with ngModel so by default it will set the calender value in the decalred variable

Comment: my question is,here i used FromDate label so whenever i click on the date in calendar then it appears in FromDate field.

Comment: You mean the value is not being event applied in calender itself or what? If an error is applying and value is not being binded then in the pickeritself there is a problem and there should be added more attributes maybe.

Comment: by using this ion calendar date picker it shows only calendar. now i want to add more attributes .on selecting date from calendar  it appears in field as a output   can you please help me in this

Comment: Ok then do as i told you . declare variable and bund it with ngModel in calender. And put the binding in the place that you need to view the value of calender.

Comment: can you please edit above code to get this . as i'm new to ionic and angular .

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ionic-calendar-date-picker                  i use this package. it shows only calendar. but i want the calendar like we use in hotel booking apps like checkin and checkout date appears on selecting dates from calendar.

Comment: Under export clas ViewPage put dateSelection:any; then in the calender put [(ngModel)]="dateSelection" and in a label or in the place tou want to show the value of calender then you just view it by {{dateSelection}}

Comment: is there any way so that i can share screenshot?

Comment: tried all the above codes. not working

Comment: 0096176303389 whatsapp the image to me and if you don't want whatsapp then prnt.sc and give the link of image.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TOltc.png this is the image of calendar i get using this link 
            npmjs.com/package/ionic-calendar-date-picker

Comment: now i want whenever i click on calendar date it appears on label. like any hotel booking app.

Comment: http://prnt.sc/r42ylq

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
dateSelected(event) {
console.log(event);

var day = event.getDate();
if (day < 10) {
  day = '0' + day;
}
// console.log(day);


var month = event.getMonth() + 1;
if (month < 10) {
  month = '0' + month;
}
// console.log(month);

var year = event.getFullYear();

var dateselected = year + '-' + month + '-' + day;
// var dateselected = day + '-' + month + '-' + year;
console.log(dateselected);


if (dateselected) {
  this.apiProvider.getListSoalanTarikh(this.color, dateselected).then(data => {
    if (data) {
      if (data.data != "No Data") {
        this.soalans = data.data;
        console.log(data);
        this.initializeItems();
      } else {
        console.log(data);
        this.soalans = '';
      }
    }
  }).catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
  }); 
}
```

}